# How can I make my Lubuntu 11.10 menus look like in 11.04?

Tags: menu, lubuntu, lxde

The menus in my Lubuntu 11.10 install look very KDE-ish. I'm using the VLC Open File...-menu as an example. In Lubuntu 11.04, a different Open File...-menu would pop up. Is there a way to make the menus look like in Lubuntu 11.04?

This is what the menus look like in Lubuntu 11.10:
[image: The VLC 'open file' menu, and the Puddletag menu look KDE-ish in 11.10]

This is what the menus look like in Lubuntu 11.04:
[image: In 11.04, the menus looked different.]

Comment: The question is: How can I make menus in Lubuntu 11.10 look like the menus in Lubuntu 11.04? The menu I showed you is the default menu in Lubuntu 11.10: I've seen it by myself by creating a Lubuntu Live USB. Resetting the menu to the defaults will get me nothing but that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a strange reason, it looks like just installing `pulseaudio` changes the menu layout to the way things were in Lubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the theme of your Lubuntu desktop. Click the LXDE button, go to Preferences and choose Customize Look and Feel. Choose your desired Icon Theme, Windows Border, Color, Widget and other UI options.

Comment: Thank you, doing this does change certain things, but the KDE-like directory structure, which I dislike most, stays the same. I will add this to the question.

Comment: you can add faenza icon set for example: first sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox and then sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the thing I'm looking for exactly. I'm looking for a way to get the menu like in 11.04. Still, thanks for your comment, I corrected the question.

Comment: The problem has been resolved by itself for some reason. Until anyone else comes up with the reason for it, I'll accept this answer as the correct one.